# Azure bot builder virtual assistant - using foreach expression in Language generation

Tags: azure, botframework

I'm following this link to create Language generation activity that accepts list of items and create carousel attachments in this activity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/language-generation/language-generation-structured-response-template?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

here I'm trying to use template manager and pass to it list of AccountInfoModel object where Account information contain property CardNumber but it fails to run and throws exception while parsing .lg files

AccountInfoModel

```
    public class AccountInfoModel
    {
        public string CardNumber;
    }
```

here is my C# code

```
            var cards = new List<AccountInfoModel>();
            cards.Add(new AccountInfoModel { CardNumber= "025-152746-020" });
            cards.Add(new AccountInfoModel { CardNumber = "025-152746-021" });

            return await sc.PromptAsync(DialogIds.AmountPrompt, new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = _templateManager.GenerateActivityForLocale("UserAccounts", cards),
            }, cancellationToken);
```

here is my .lg looks like

````
# UserAccounts
[Activity
    Attachments = ${foreach($cardValues, item, AccountInfoCardJson(item)}
    AttachmentLayout = carousel
]

# AccountInfoCardJson (item)
- ```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": ${CardNumber},
                    "wrap": true,
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                }]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Select Account",
            "text": "Select Account",
            "data": "${CardNumber}"
        }
    ]
}
````